# registering sip as protocol in Ubuntu 18 to use TbDialout with Thunderbird and Ekiga

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, sip, ekiga

Using Ubuntu 18 with Gnome, i would like to to connect Thundebird addressbook with ekiga, using a SIP provider for phonecalls.

Ekiga works fine standanlone.

TBDialout (Version 1.8.0pre1, for thunderbird 68.7.0) is configured with a userdefined url with this form:

```
sip:%NUM%@sip.finotel.com
```

Pushing the call-Button out of the thunderbird addressbook leads to an error: sip is not a registered protocol or not allowed in this context.

Following the TBDialout-Wiki, i registered SIP protocol
https://www.oak-wood.co.uk/faq/content/5/14/en/how-do-i-register-a-url-handler-for-the-sip-protocol-in-gnome-_-ubuntu.html

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/sip/command '/usr/bin/ekiga -c %s' --type String
```

I am not shure, whether this is the proper way to register an uri protocol in ubuntu 18/gnome.
And i am not shure, wether this is the reason for the error message.

But it nevertheless still runs into the same error message.

Any suggestions would be great ...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You still configure TBDialout with a userdefined url as written above.

But the method described above how to register SIP protocol as an url-handler is outdated.

Now you do this this way:

Create a file `~/.local/share/applications/sipurl.desktop` and put this in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/ekiga -c %u
Name=sip-url
Comment=sip-url handler
Icon=
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/sip;
```

Then run

```
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler sip sipurl.desktop
```

Credits go to Chris Hastie, author of TbDialout.

https://github.com/tipichris/TBDialOut/issues/12